# Recycler view in fragment

Tags: android

i am working on app .in which i want to do like, when i click on one button it will start fragment , and in fragment i have created a recycler view. Recycler view will show the list of songs in device. but problem is only fragment shows. no layout for recyclerview or even recycler view.
here is my fragment class,recycler view is in fragment class:

```
public class Fragment_song extends Fragment {

//ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songs;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
SongAdapter mAdapter;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.song_layout, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_View);

    // mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(songs);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mAdapter=new SongAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    return v;
}


public void SongList() {
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION
    };
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";

    Cursor cur = cr.query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            selection,
            null,
            sortOrder);

    mAdapter.songs = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
      /*  songs.add(cur.getString(0) + "||"
                + cur.getString(1) + "||"
                + cur.getString(2) + "||"
                + cur.getString(3) + "||"
                + cur.getString(4) + "||" );*/

        map.put("ID", cur.getString(0));
        map.put("artist", cur.getString(1));
        map.put("title", cur.getString(2));
        map.put("displayname", cur.getString(3));
        map.put("duration", cur.getString(4));

        mAdapter.songs.add(map);


    }

}

 }
```

my Adapter for Recycler View. please in this ..because at run time ,sometimes i got like no adapter attached. skipping layout.!

```
public class SongAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SongAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songs=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>() ;





@Override
public SongAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview, parent, false);

    MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //Movie movie = moviesList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(songs.get(position).get("displayname"));
    holder.artist.setText(songs.get(position).get("artist"));
    holder.duration.setText(songs.get(position).get("duration"));
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return songs.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, duration, artist;


    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        artist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist);
        duration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration);
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to call SongList() in onCreateView()

Answer (score 0):

Now,what you're doing is rendering a list which has no elements inside in you're adapter.
try this.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.song_layout, container, false);
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_View);

// mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(songs);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
mAdapter=new SongAdapter();
SongList();
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
return v;
}
```

Comment: one more thing.! if you can help.. my recycler view is ready .but when i scroll it up to down ,there is space created between items of the recyclerview .!! why so? @farhan patel